AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'imread' but no file name cv2.py
(I'm using VScode on Mac)
I can import cv2, but it went wrong when running image = cv2.imread(path, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR).
I get this error:
 image = cv2.imread(path, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
            ^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'imread'

I run print(dir(cv2)) and get this:
['__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__']

There is a similar question on stackoverflow, it says that I might have a cv2.py file. However, I have checked that and cv2 still work on my Mac yesterday. Also, I have tried reinstalling opencv-python and opencv-contrib-python for several time, but it still don't work.
When using conda, I install opencv by running conda install -c conda-forge opencv , but I result in ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'.
How can I fix this? Thx!!

I have faced this before. Go to you python installation (probably home/YOUR_USR/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages)  and see if there is a folder called cv2 and delete it... and the re-insall opencv

you must browse previous questions. [tour], [ask], [mre]. DO NOT install multiple opencv packages. they conflict.
